# When configuring CI for a Firebase project, should I use a Firebase token or a GCP service account key?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, firebase-cli

When configuring CI for a Firebase project, [I often see references](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-firebase) to either a `FIREBASE_TOKEN` generated with `firebase login:ci` or a service account key that (I think) is generated by default for each project.

For my particular use case, I want to do the following:

- run *online* tests (with Firestore) against my `test` project when running `npm run test` during my CI build
- deploy that code to a different `prod` project if tests pass

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the `FIREBASE_TOKEN`. As usually, tokens are better to use, as you can quickly cancel or renew in any issue that you might have it, as well it's easier to manage them a service account and to insert them in the code.

Besides that, the official Firebase documentation - [Use the CLI with CI systems](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems) - indicates and teaches how to use it with the token, so it seems that indeed, using the token is the best and easier option for you to implement.

Comment: From what I can tell it actually looks like Firebase tokens are just a convenient shortcut for a key from the default Firebase admin-sdk service account.  After trying both approaches I now see a key under each respective service account at console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/details/. 

So to your point, the default Firebase admin-sdk service account (which is used by FIREBASE_TOKEN) seems to have the necessary privileges that GCP expects a CI server to need. If those privileges are too broad then a custom service account might be preferred.